# Remove last list item from DynamoDB?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DynamoDB / Amazon Web Services with their SDK Object Persistence Model.  I have an object type that has some basic parameters and some lists that are stored.  This works fine and the lists are stored as string sets on the DB.  To save the objects back to the DB I'm simply calling:

```
context.Save<AwsProject>(project);
```

This is working fine as long as the list isn't empty.  If I have had items in the list and then remove the last one, creating an empty list, this does not save, the last item stays in there...

What am I missing?  Is there something else I need to do to clear out that last value?

Comment: Can you post the code for your AwsProject class please. Might help us work out what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just got back to this and I think I must have been doing something else in my code that was not letting it remove properly.  I worked on a few other things and fixed some issues in the saving and when I came back to address this it's gone.  Removing the last item from my collection and then using the context to save the object now removes the attribute without me expressly doing it.  Sorry for the confusion but it looks like their API does indeed handle this as I would expect...

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB doesn't support empty sets. See the very last sentence of the [DynamoDB Naming Rules and Data Types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes) article. If your list is empty, you should completely delete the attribute that is storing the list.

Comment: Hmm, I missed that, thanks for the link.  I would think that the object persistence framework in their SDK would recognize that and remove the attribute but I guess not.  So I guess I will have to make a special case to handle this in code and remove the attribute myself.  Is there a way to remove attributes through the context or do I need to go down to a lower level?

Comment: I do not know about that, as I have not used their C# SDK directly. Using the Ruby SDK, I test for "empty-ness" or "blank-ness" and then set the action on the attribute to DELETE instead of PUT. Perhaps, someone else with C# experience can help answer your question.

Comment: So per my above answer I think it was my user error and their SDK/API does handle it has I would expect.  I'm up-voting your answer and comment for taking the time to provide useful information but posted my own as the accepted answer.